# Get a char* from an ostream without copying

Tags: c++, char, copy, buffer, ostream

I have an `ostream` and data has been written to it. Now I want that data in the form of a `char` array. Is there a way to get the char buffer and its size without copying all of the bytes? I mean, I know I can use `ostringstream` and call `str().c_str()` on it but that produces a temporary copy.

Comment: Can you use `sprintf`?

Comment: What does sprintf have to do with ostream?

Comment: well if you can write to an `std::ostringstream` then what prevents you from writing directly to a C string with `sprintf`?

Comment: Well, then I'd have to replace all of the ostream::write calls with sprintf calls, and then my code would only be able to write directly to a C string.

Comment: Can you clarify whether you need to be able to do this for all `ostream` objects, or just `ostringstream`?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with making a copy of the buffer. You haven't even explained how it could be a potential bottleneck in your program.

Comment: create your own subclass of `streambuf`.

Comment: I'm not judging anyone who makes a copy of a buffer. But I'm working with a large amount of data and I would like to avoid it if possible. I like to write efficient code, not just when there are potential bottlenecks.

Comment: @CantChooseUsernames can you please elaborate?

Comment: @BrianBi ostringstream would be ok, since it is an ostream.

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you saying that you can use any kind of `ostream` to perform the task, but you *must* use *some* kind of `ostream`? Why is that?

Comment: Yes, because the functions that write the data take an `ostream` and don't care what kind. Once they have written the data I want to get the char array.

Comment: Hey @0x499602D2, what happened to your answer?

Comment: @rmp251 I will put it back up for you. I thought it wasn't helping which was why I removed it at first. Sorry. :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Well, I was hoping for a much simpler answer. But I appreciate the answer and would like to give you credit even if I don't end up using it.

Comment: If you need a string representation of a stream object, then use `std::stringstream`. And as I said there's nothing wrong with making a temporary copy of the buffer, that's the way the stream was designed and meant to be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this is what you're looking for - a stream buffer that returns a pointer to its buffer:

```c++
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class raw_buffer : public std::streambuf
{
public:
    raw_buffer(std::ostream& os, int buf_size = 256);
    int_type overflow(int_type c) override;
    std::streamsize showmanyc() override;
    std::streamsize xsputn(const char_type*, std::streamsize) override; 
    int sync() override;
    bool flush();
    std::string const& str() const;
private:
    std::ostream& os_;
    std::vector<char> buffer;
    std::string aux;
};
```

Now `str()` is simple. It returns a pointer to the underlying buffer of the auxillary buffer:

```c++
std::string const& raw_buffer::str() const
{
    return aux;
}
```

The rest of the functions are the usual implementations for a stream buffer. `showmanyc()` should return the size of the auxiliary buffer (`aux` is just a running total of the entire buffer, `buffer` on the other hand is the size specified at construction).

For example, here is `overflow()`, which should update both buffers at same time but still treat `buffer` as the primary buffer:

```c++
raw_buffer::int_type raw_buffer::overflow(raw_buffer::int_type c) override
{   
    if (os_ && !traits_type::eq_int_type(c, traits_type::eof()))
    {
        aux += *this->pptr() = traits_type::to_char_type(c);
        this->pbump(1);

        if (flush())
        {
            this->pbump(-(this->pptr() - this->pbase()));
            this->setp(this->buffer.data(),
                       this->buffer.data() + this->buffer.size());
            return c;
        } 
    }
    return traits_type::eof();
}
```

`flush()` is used to copy the contents of `buffer` to the stream (`os_`), and `sync()` should be overrided to call `flush()` too.

`xsputn` also needs to be overrided to write to `aux` as well:

```c++
std::streamsize raw_buffer::xsputn(const raw_buffer::char_type* str, std::streamsize count) override
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (traits_type::eq_int_type(this->sputc(str[i]), traits_type::eof()))
            return i;
        else
            aux += str[i];
    }
    return count;
}
```

Now we can put this together with a customized stream:

```c++
class raw_ostream : private virtual raw_buffer
                  , public std::ostream
{
public:
    raw_ostream(std::ostream& os) : raw_buffer(os)
                                  , std::ostream(this)
    { }

    std::string const& str() const
    {
        return this->raw_buffer::str();
    }

    std::streamsize count()
    {
        return this->str().size();
    }
};
```

It can be used like this:

```c++
int main()
{
    raw_ostream rostr(std::cout);
    rostr << "Hello, World " << 123 << true << false;

    auto& buf = rostr.str();
    std::cout << buf;
}
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I haven't tried to run this code. You can play around with it a bit to get it to compile if I've made any mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Does aux.c_str() not return a copy?

Comment: @rmp251 In the case of a `std::stringstream`, it is `str()` that returns a temporary copy of the buffer.

Comment: @rmp251 Sorry. I should've been returing a `std::string&` instead of `char const*`. I've changed it.

Comment: @rmp251 Update: Turns out I actually got it to work! [Please see this demo](http://ideone.com/pC7PiR).